# List not aligned?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I was hoping this is a simple issue and me being dumb. I have just run PCA on my dataset which is 18093 rows and 13626 columns and when I run the below code I get the error below. I am pretty sure I am not indexing correctly - can someone see what I am missing? This is the first time running the code for me.

My objective is to pull the top two eigen pairs. In Python 2.7

```
# Choosing optimal number of eigen pairs
num_eigen_pairs = np.hstack((eigen_pairs[0][1][:, np.newaxis], eigen_pairs[1][1][:, np.newaxis]))

len(num_eigen_pairs)
Out[161]: 18093

X_train1[0]
Out[162]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])

len(X_train1)
Out[163]: 18093

X_train1.dot(num_eigen_pairs) #This is the line erroring out
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "", line 1, in 
> >             X_train1.dot(num_eigen_pairs)
> >
> > > ValueError: shapes (18093,13626) and (18093,2) not aligned: 13626 (dim
> > >       1) != 18093 (dim 0)

Comment: I think you have to transpose one of them.  dimensions have to be <a,b>*<b,c> in matrix multiplication.  try `X_train1.T.dot(num_eigen_pairs)
`

Comment: `A.dot(B)` requires that the last dimension of `A` match the 2nd to the last dimension (first for 2d) of `B`.

Comment: @Mohammad Athar Thank you! Yes, that worked! Genius :-)

Comment: @Alvis great! I posted it as an answer, please accept and upvote if you'd like

Answer (score 2):

You have to transpose one of them. dimensions have to be of the form `<a,b>*<b,c>` in matrix multiplication. try

```
X_train1.T.dot(num_eigen_pairs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect